# Make Project fails but Build Signed APK works in Android Studio. How do they differ?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-plugin-3.3.0

I have a multi module project that I just inherited.  I'm able to build and debug the app as well as create signed APK.  However, when I try to clean and then make the project (release flavour) the build fails.  Error generated refers to a theme that connot be found.  I did verify that the theme is present in one of the modules.

I'm going to spend some time to figure out why the theme is not found when I make release flavour.  However, I'm somewhat confused why creating signed APK (also release flavour) works.  I always thought that in both cases a similar gradle script is being executed.

Can someone please explain the difference, if any?

I'm using Android Sutdio 3.3.

Comment: you probably should explain the problem first... by adding `build.gradle` and/or logcat. alike it is currently written, we are talking about some imaginary project, with some imaginary problem.

Answer (score 0):

- File --> Invalidate Caches-->Restart
- then from build--> make project
- I think this can solve your problem

  [image: follow this]